# Python Regx gives none answer

Tags: python, regex

I wanted to extract PAN from the message

```
PAN=re.compile(r"[a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]")
mes="ITR for AY 2019-20 for PAN: apzxxxxx9g has been processed at CPC"
abc=PAN.search(mes)
print(abc)
```

output: `None`

Comment: Can you give a real example of the input string (no `x`s) and the matching expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to extract `xxxxx9g`, you use `4` repetitions of the number, which cannot yield a correct match.

You can change it to 1 to 4 numbers (`[0-9]{1,4}`):

```
PAN=re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9]{1,4}[a-zA-Z]')
mes="ITR for AY 2019-20 for PAN: apzxxxxx9g has been processed at CPC"
abc=PAN.search(mes)
print(abc)
```

output: `<re.Match object; span=(31, 38), match='xxxxx9g'>`

```
>>> print(abc.group())
xxxxx9g
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is looking for five alphabetic characters, followed by four digits, followed by one alphabetic. Nothing in your string matches (`apzxxxxx9g` is close, but exactly three of the `x`s immediately preceding `9` would need to be digits). Either your input needs to change, or your regex does.